# all solutions of linear inequality system

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I have a linear inequality system in the form $Ax=b, 0 \leq x$.
How can I get all the possible solutions?
I suppose it must be a convex combination of some vectors - but how do I find these vectors?

Comment: It's not clear to me what 0<=x should mean.

Comment: @S.M.Roch: It means that all components of x, which is a vector, is at least zero, so none of them is negative.

Comment: Googling "simplex algorithm" should help

Comment: What do you mean exactly?  $Ax=b$ has in general a unique solution and for $0\le x$ there are a lot of candidates for $x$, for $A$ and for $b$ In what $\mathbb R^n$ do you place your problem?

Comment: @Peter: I know about the simplex algorithm. It requires a function, of which it optimizes the value, and gives a single solution. However, I need all the possible values of x.

Comment: @Piquito: I mean those lot of candidates for x. x has 7 elements, b has 3 or 4.